# Dodge Caravan 2000 sudden rev

Tags: engine, dodge, caravan

My Dodge Caravan 2000 suddenly revs at high speeds. When travelling at 70km/h, the rpm would suddenly go from 1.5k to 2-2.5k instantly and jerks afterward.

I'm not really a car guy so if you guys can help me out that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though your transmission is slipping or allowing the engine to rev. Once the transmission catches back up, it slams back into gear causing the jerk you are suggesting. This could easily be caused by a lack of (or low) transmission fluid.